# xAxis and navigator don't update according to series

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

i need to update an highchart made with angular according with some filters, this is the initial chart:

[image]

and this is the filtered chart:

[image]

im using: [hightcharts-ng](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng) with Highstock

as you can see there is an issue with xAxis, it wont update.
Im using this code for update the chart:

```
$scope.chartConfigTotGiorni.xAxis.categories = categories;
$scope.chartConfigTotGiorni.series[0].data = data;
$scope.chartConfigTotGiorni.getHighcharts().redraw();
```

elso tried:

```
$scope.chartConfigTotGiorni.getHighcharts().xAxis[0].update({categories: categories});
$scope.chartConfigTotGiorni.getHighcharts().series[0].setData(data);
$scope.chartConfigTotGiorni.getHighcharts().redraw();
```

but nothing change. I ve also tried with the setExtremes() function with any result....

EDIT:

[image]

after updating the second series (navigator) the view is still bad, seems that i ve a -1 value at the beginning and other values in the end, i cant figure out how fix this

[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m0v3s2y8/)

Comment: What angular plugin/wrapper for Highcharts are you using? Could you post a live example, like jsFiddle? Looks like navigator series is not updated - you should be able to do that manually by updating second series (technically it should the last series in chart.series array that is a navigator series). With clean (without angular) Highstock it works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/d60m8tqr/

Comment: Oh!!! that was easy.... the navigator series its just at series[1].... ok now seems to work a little bit better.... i just need to adjust the extremes

Comment: Extremes for axis can be set dynamically using [`Axis.setExtremes()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.setExtremes)

Comment: setting the extremes dont fix the issue

Comment: Without a working demo it will be hard to ques what might be wrong.

Comment: ill try to make one

Comment: ok i ve done a fiddle that create my issue

Comment: If you won't update second xAxis, then chart looks fine after update - http://jsfiddle.net/m0v3s2y8/1/